# Possible to set event.dataTransfer asynchronously after drag start?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, dom-events

Currently I am working on a scenario that I need to change the data attached to a dragging element after the dragging starts. Basically the drop zones are input fields or textareas so i would like to use the native `event.dataTransfer.setData` since the native drag-drop can make the caret move with mouse.

Everything works perfectly at the beginning if i just call the `setData()` synchronously in the listener of `dragstart` event.

```
dragItem.addEventListener("dragstart",function(event){  
     event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain","data set in dragstart");
})
```

However, my scenario could be that the data is from an asynchronouly callback function like an AJAX request. Then I attempted to call `setData()` in this callback function but nothing seems to be successfully set.

```
dragItem.addEventListener("dragstart",function(event){

  event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain","data set in dragstart");

  //like a callback in Ajax or resolve function of a promise.
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("attempt to set data asynchonrously after drag start");
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain","asynchonrously set data");

    //looks like failed, the console output is empty, even not the original set one
    console.log(event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain"));
  },200)

})
```

I also tried to change the data in `dragenter` and even `drop` event listeners of the drop zones. But there was still no luck.

This [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bOeMoDpaKJRj1uZhZVdW?p=preview) shows what i have tried.

Then i referred to the [MDN API document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) to find offical api description of the `dataTransfer` object. But there is nothing about problems like asynchronously using `setData` after drag start. One really weird thing is that if i try to compare the two `dataTransfer` references in `dragstart` and `drop` event, the are NOT the same object. Now I have no clue what is actually happening.

**So my questions are**

1. Is it possible to set the data in `dataTransfer` after the dragging is started with the native APIs (without using `event.preventDefault`) ?
2. If the first question's answer is NO, what kind of workaround could I try? **I could think of something about how to save and get the data to transfer. My main concern is that if `event.preventDefault()` is used on `drop`, it is not easy to get the caret move with mouse like the native dropping does.**

Comment: What is purpose of setting `event.dataTransfer` asynchronously? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer.
Firstly,You can only set data in your **dragstart** event. So, every time any **dragstart** event starts it sets value and what ever you set asynchronouly will not get reflected no matter what.

So, one thing that you can do is have a global object and set that on drag start event like this:

```
var someObj = {
   asd : 'something'
}
```

and set in you **dragstart** callback, like this:

```
dragItem.addEventListener("dragstart",function(event){

      event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", someObj.asd);
      dataTransferObject = event.dataTransfer;

      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("attempt to set data asynchonrously after drag start");
        //event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain","asynchonrously set data");

        someObj.asd = 'asynchonrously';
        //looks like failed, the console output is empty
        console.log(event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain"));
      }, 100)

    })
```

Object is by default reference type.
Now, You can set *someObj.asd* to any value you want and you will see new value reflected. But there is a problem with this approach, value will be reflected after drop happens means after event has been ended.

So, to solve your problem what you can do is don't set any value on **dragstart** just set some value to *someObj.asd* on drag start and use *someObj.asd* on drop.

Here is a link of what i'm trying to explain:
https://plnkr.co/edit/SZhI9lGRI37eEd1nWfhn?p=preview

**see console on drop event** you will see reflected value there.

> DON'T SEE UI JUST GO FOR CONSOLE

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Saving it in a global object is a good idea. But what I wan't to achieve is to insert the saved text to that textarea or a content editable div at cursor position (keeping track of mouse position like native). So after giving an NO to the first question, the critical problem of workaround is how can i use the global object on drop to insert the text at the right position.

Comment: you can write javascript to do that for you.

Comment: Well, that is true. But i will not be so struggling if this can be easily done. Nor can i find any library helping me achieve that. So i am still facing this problem and cannot find a way to solve it with your current answer. I need the ui to update properly.